# Is this possible without introducing Javascript or adding to the HTML?

Tags: html, css

My client wants every link list, that is, every list of the form

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="www.google.com">Here's a link</a>  
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="www.google.com">Here's a link</a>          
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="www.google.com">Here's a link</a>          
    </li>
</ul>
```

to have the bullets of the list be the same color as the linked text, but every non-link list, that is, every list of the form

```
<ul>
     <li>Here's a regular list item</li>   
     <li>Here's a regular list item</li>
     <li>Here's a regular list item</li>
</ul>
```

should have its bullets and corresponding text inherit as usual.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0kkc2rz4/

I am constrained by not being able to add classes into the `HTML`, so something like

```
<ul class='link-list'>
    <li>
        <a href="www.google.com">Here's a link</a>  
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="www.google.com">Here's a link</a>          
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="www.google.com">Here's a link</a>          
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

```
ul.link-list li { color: #004E98; }
```

is out of the question, although I realize that's the obviously best way to do it if I was coding the site from scratch. I can add JS, but would prefer not to.

Comment: Say what you are trying to do in the title of the question.

Comment: Here's the answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector - summary: as of right now, this is not possible to do with pure CSS

Comment: Are you able to add Font Awesome (http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) ? If so it will be helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution using a pseudo element and the unicode character for bullet points. The basic idea is to 'overlap' the `a` bullet over the `li` bullet, giving the effect that they are different.

```css
ul{
  margin:0em;
  padding:0em;
  list-style:none;
  padding:20px 20px 0px 20px;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}


li{
  margin:0em;
  padding:0em;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}

a{
  color:red;
  text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover{
  color:green;
}

a, li{
  position:relative;
}

a:before, li:before{
  content:'\2022';
  position:absolute;
  left:-0.5em; 
  color:inherit;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="www.google.com">Here's a link</a>  
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="www.google.com">Here's a link</a>          
    </li>
    <li>
        Here's a regular list item       
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So is there no way to do this without re-creating the bullet (essentially) with :before selectors? This seems to just be another situation of needing to select a parent of something, which can't be done in css. I was hoping to see a weird solution that might involve something like the :not selector, but I don't think there is one.

Comment: @ferr not that I know of, unfortunately. Behind the scenes the browser is ultimately just doing the same thing: adding a `•` `:before` each list item. This just does the same thing to the `a` tag and overlaps them. We just need to do it again for the `li` for cross-browser normalizing.

Answer (score 1):

Playing a bit with pseudolements: http://jsfiddle.net/2acw2hae/1/

```
ul { list-style: none; }

ul a { position: relative; }

ul a:before { 
    content : "\25CF"; /* unicode for black circle */
    font-size: 0.75em; 
    margin-right: .5em;
}

/* this overlaps the text-decoration under the bullet */
ul a:after { 
    content : "";
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0; left: 0; 
    height:4px; 
    width: .5em; 
    background: #fff; 
}
```

Result

[image]